# Integrating a JMenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

This my Mainframe

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private ToolBar tb;
    private JeuPanel panel;

    MainFrame() {
        super("TP1");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel = new JeuPanel();
        tb = new ToolBar();

        setJMenuBar(tb);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

This is my toolbar class:

```
public class ToolBar extends JFrame {

    private JMenuBar monMenu;
    private JMenu menuFichier;
    private JMenuItem menuDemarrer;
    private JMenuItem menuQuitter;

    public ToolBar() {
    }

    public ToolBar(String title) {
        monMenu = new JMenuBar();

        menuFichier = new JMenu("Menu");
        this.menuDemarrer = new JMenuItem("Demarrer");
        this.menuQuitter = new JMenuItem("Quitter");

        menuQuitter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        monMenu.add(menuFichier);
        menuFichier.add(menuDemarrer);
        menuFichier.add(menuQuitter);

        this.setJMenuBar(monMenu);

        this.setSize(300, 200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setVisible(true);

    }
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: tp1.prog.MainFrame.setJMenuBar
    at tp1.prog.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:27)
    at tp1.prog.TP1Prog.main(TP1Prog.java:20)
```

Hi,

I don't understand why I can't set my JMenu. It says the class Toolbar cannot be to JMenuBar

Thanks

Comment: Show code and possible error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image.

Comment: _In the question_, not as comment.

Comment: **In the question**

Comment: The `ToolBar` class is a JFrame. It can't be used as menu bar as you try in `MainFrame` constructor. In the constructor of `ToolBar` you are doing it right by creating and modifying a real `JMenuBar` which is finally set as menu bar for `ToolBar`.

Comment: For what do you need `ToolBar` in `MainFrame`? Maybe you should simply move the menu bar construction code from `ToolBar` to `MainFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a getter method of monMenu in ToolBar.java
Then modified as in Mainframe.java

```
tb = new ToolBar("abc");

setJMenuBar(tb.getMonMenu());
```